# using InStrRev() and similar functions in Jet/ACE queries outside of Access

Tags: ms-access, jet

Hia, I'm struggling a bit while forming some SQL queries.
Currently I'm using:

```
InStrRev(TABLE.[_URL],"/")+1) AS OUTPUT
```

Given an input of a URL - I want to extract the last part eg:

```
www.url.com/some/text/here
```

Should return

```
here
```

There are always 3 slashes and while the snippet I posted works perfectly; only within access.

When I try and use this outside of access - I find errors - any advice on alternatives available to me?

Comment: I think the most efficient approach would be to get the required string on the display side, rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, SQL queries executed from within Access can use many VBA functions (like `InStr()` and `InStrRev()`) that are not natively supported by the Jet/ACE dialect of SQL. One of the most powerful aspects of Access' "extensions" to Jet/ACE SQL is that you can even write your own VBA functions and use *them* in Access queries.

Unfortunately, things can get a bit confusing when it comes to what functions are supported in "plain" Jet/ACE SQL because many of the names are the same. If we can use `Left()`, `Right()`, `Mid()`, etc. in queries against Jet/ACE databases executed outside of Access, then why not `InStr()` and `InstrRev()`? The answer is, unfortunately, "Just because.".

In your particular case I agree with Remou's comment that you'll probably just have to retrieve the entire column value in your query and then do the [equivalent of the] `InStrRev()`-related parsing afterward.

Comment: Well it's a bit disappointing - and irritating that the "dialects" are  missing bits of each other!
I've worked around the original issue for now by changing the incoming data in such a way that there is only one slash in the input string, thus allowing "plain JET" functions to parse it.
Thank you for the explanation though :)