# Is there any replacement for the InstrRev function in Microsoft Access 2016 for a calculated column?

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to create several calculated columns in a table with different parts of a parsed filename. Using the InstrRev function is critical to isolate the base file name or extension, but InstrRev is not supported in calculated columns.

I know that there are other ways to solve my problem that don't use calculated columns, but does anyone have a valid calculated column formula that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

Access lets you use VBA functions (including user-defined functions) directly from within a SQL query - however they only work within an Access context - if you have another frontend for a JET (now ACE) database - or inside a computed/calculated column, they won't work - as you've just discovered.

Unfortunately Access (JET and ACE) have only a very meagre and anaemic selection of built-in functions, and the platform has now lagged-behind SQL Server (and even the open-source SQLite) significantly - Access 2016 has not made significant changes to its SQL implementation since Access 2000 (16 years of stagnation!) whereas SQL Server 2016's T-SQL language is so evolved it's almost unrecognizable compared to SQL Server 2000.

JET and ACE support the standard ODBC functions ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208907(v=office.12).aspx ) however none of these perform a "reverse index-of" operation. Also absent is any form of pattern-matching function - though the `LIKE` operator works, it only returns a boolean result, not a character index.

In short: what you want to do is impossible.

This has been discovered by many people before you:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6cf82b1b-8e74-4ac8-9997-61cad8bb9310/access-database-engine-incompatible-with-instrrev?forum=accessdev

  > He maintains a list of DAO/Jet/etc reserved words - and on that list you will see the InstrRev is a VBA() function, and is not a part of the Jet/Ace Engines.
- [using InStrRev() and similar functions in Jet/ACE queries outside of Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633533/using-instrrev-and-similar-functions-in-jet-ace-queries-outside-of-access)

  > As you have discovered, SQL queries executed from within Access can use many VBA functions that are not natively supported by the Jet/ACE dialect of SQL

That said, computed/calculated columns are only really of use in stored `VIEW` objects ("Queries" objects in Access parlance)  - which in turn are used for user convenience, not for any programming advantage - especially as these are scalar functions that are evaluated for every row of data that the engine processes (making them potentially very expensive and inefficient to run).

...so the only real solution is to abandon computed/calculated columns and perform this processing in your own application code - but the advantage is that your program will likely be significantly faster.

...or don't use Access and switch to a different DBMS with better active support, such as SQLite (for an in-process database), SQL Server (now with `LocalDb` for in-process support), or VistaDB (proprietary, but 100% Managed code). Note that Access also supports acting as a front-end for a SQL Server "backend" data-store - where you could create a `VIEW` that performs this operation, then query the view from your Access code or other consuming client.

There is a workaround if you must: Create a duplicate column that contains the string-reversed value of your original column, then you can evaluate the ODBC `LOCATE` or JET SQL `InStr` functions on it and get the result you want (albiet, reversed) - but this would require double the storage space.

e.g.

```
RowId, FileName , FileNameRev
1    , 'Foo.txt', 'txt.ooF'
2    , 'Bar.txt', 'txt.raB'
```

Comment: Wow, that was precise, succinct and rapid! I searched what I could, but was unaware of the mixture of Jet and VBA in SQL processing. I completely agree that Access is a sub-par solution for most things. I will add the code because at this point processing of queries relying on the InstrRev functions are hideously slow.

Comment: @PatientZero Note that string suffix operations (such as `InStrRev` and `LIKE %suffix`) are generally bad for queries because they aren't Sargable and therefore must evaluate every row.

Comment: @Dai: You seem to forget that the questioneer operates in an Access 2016 environment, so while your comments are valid in a broader sense, you cannot claim that _what you want to do is impossible_ when a simple query will fill the task.

Comment: @Gustav You cannot use VBA functions in a calculated field - that's what I explained (because it's a core part of JET/ACE and independent of Access) and it's what the OP was asking.

Comment: You are so right, but you left out the simple and even preferable workaround.

Comment: @Gustav For me, Dai answered the question perfectly. I stated that I knew there were other solutions, but I was pointedly asking only about calculated columns, which based on his answer I have abandoned.

Comment: That's a wise decision.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any calculated field. It's a "super user" feature only, that will cause you nothing but trouble. Calculated fields - or expressions - belong in a query.

So create a simple select query:

```
Select 
    *,
    InStrRev([FieldToCheck], "YourMatchingString") As StringMatch
From
    YourTable
```

Save the query, and then use this whenever you need the table values and this expression.

Comment: While it wasn't in my question the reason that I looked at calculated fields was that some of my queries that were using InstrRev were painfully slow, so I need to have them as stored values in order to index them.

Comment: @PatientZero Calculated columns would not have helped you - calculated columns are not stored, they're recomputed when accessed, so even if Access did support `InStrRev` it would have been just as slow.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, and the rest of your support, I really appreciate it. I guess if I had gone that way I would have quickly noticed that it didn't help performance. I started off looking for the equivalent of an On Insert event at the table level which Access also doesn't support in the way I would like. In the end I have changed the code in the app to do what I want and now the 10 minutes query is instantaneous. Of course, if I could have picked the architecture I wouldn't have chosen Access.